# Ruby aws device farm throwing argument error when calling schedule_run method

Tags: ruby, appium, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to schedule a run using the aws device farm sdk, I have followed the documentation, however, every time I call the schedule_run method I get this error:
`Aws::DeviceFarm::Errors::ArgumentException: Missing or unprocessed resources`

This is the method from where I'm calling schedule_run:

```
def schedule_run
aws_client.schedule_run({
project_arn: ANDROID_PROJECT_ARN, # required
app_arn: get_uploads_by_name(ANDROID_APP, 'ANDROID_APP').arn,
device_pool_arn: get_device_pool_by_name('Android test decive pool').arn,
device_selection_configuration: nil,
name: "test_run",
test: { # required
type: "APPIUM_RUBY",
test_package_arn: get_uploads_by_name(TEST_SUITE, 'APPIUM_RUBY_TEST_PACKAGE').arn,
test_spec_arn: get_uploads_by_name('aws_android_4.yml', 'APPIUM_RUBY_TEST_SPEC').arn,
filter: nil,
parameters: nil
},
configuration: {
extra_data_package_arn: nil,
network_profile_arn: get_network_profile_by_name('Full').arn,
locale: "en_US",
location: {
latitude: 47.6204, # required
longitude: 122.3491 # required
},
vpce_configuration_arns: nil,
customer_artifact_paths: {
ios_paths: nil,
android_paths: nil,
device_host_paths: %w[/tmp/allure-results /tmp/screenshots]
},
radios: {
wifi: true,
bluetooth: false,
nfc: true,
gps: true
},
auxiliary_apps: nil,
billing_method: "UNMETERED" # accepts METERED, UNMETERED
},
execution_configuration: {
job_timeout_minutes: 150,
accounts_cleanup: false,
app_packages_cleanup: false,
video_capture: false,
skip_app_resign: false
}
})
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception `Missing or unprocessed resources` typically means that there was an issue with one of your uploads. Use the [`GetUpload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_GetUpload.html) on of your uploads to see what went wrong.